# Multiple Pricing Discount Promotions w/o Coupon Code

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be simple, but I can't get it to work. I am trying to write 3 Shopping Cart level pricing rules for the following scenarios:

5% off over $45
10% off over $65
15% off over $100

The rules should cancel each other out to function properly. For example, if someone spends over $100 they should only get 15% off their total and not the combination of all rules: 30%.

Anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up three individual shopping cart price rules with priorities, "15% off" having the highest priority. Then set "stop further rule processing" to "yes" so that as soon as the first rule matches, the others are not added.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering my own question after thinking more about the problem. I decided to write all 3 rules to work independently so that once one was not applied due to the criteria, the next one would be applied.

I changed the qualifying dollar amount thresholds for each to ranges.

Ex 1: If Order is > or = $50 AND < $75, then apply 10% off cart subtotal.
Ex 2: If Order is > or = $75 AND < $150, then apply 15% off cart subtotal.